# Advanced Queries in REST

Tags: rest

I'm trying to create a more advanced query mechanism for REST. Assume I have the following:

```
GET  /data/users
```

and it returns a list of users. Then to filter the users returned for example I'd say:

```
GET /data/users?age=30
```

to get a list of 30 year old users. Now lets say I want users aged 30 - 40. I'd like to have essentially a set of reusable operators such as:

```
GET /data/users?greaterThan(age)=30&lessThan(age)=40
```

The greaterThan and lessThan would be reusable on other numeric, date, etc fields. This would also allow me to add other operators (contains, starts with, ends with, etc). I'm a REST noob so I'm not sure if this violates any of the core principles REST follows. Any thoughts?

Comment: MS Dynamics 2011 platform does something similar with the oData interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx Maybe this will give you some info.

Comment: Wow thanks for the link, that's really helpful to see how someone like Microsoft implemented it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, it's been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you might simply be better off with optional parameters "minAge" and "maxAge".

Alternative 2:  encode the value(s) for parameters to indicate the test to be performed: inequalities, pattern matching etc.

This gets messy no matter what you do for complex boolean expressions.  At some point, you almost want to make a document format for the query description itself, but it's hard to think of it as a "GET" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into setting the value of the query parameter to include syntax for operators and such .. something like this for a range of values

```
/data/users?age=[30,40]
```

or

```
/data/users?age=>30&age=<40
```

would make it a little easier to read, just make sure to url encode if you are using any reserved characters